# JsonConvert object to datagridview c#

Tags: c#, json, datagridview

I have deserialized and converted my JSON string to an object.

I want to know how I can place all this data into a `DataGridView`?

I've searched the forums but can't find a suitable answer. Here's what I have:

JSON:

```
{
  "name":"default",
  "ramps":[
    {
      "color":"deep_red",
      "points": [
        {"time":0,"intensity":0},
        {"time":360,"intensity":0},
        /* MANY OTHER POINTS */
        {"time":1290,"intensity":0}
      ]
    },
    {
      "color":"uv",
      "points":[
        {"time":0,"intensity":0},
        /* MANY OTHER POINTS */
        {"time":1290,"intensity":0}
      ]
    },
    {
      "color":"deep_blue",
      "points":[
        {"time":0,"intensity":0},
        /* MANY OTHER POINTS */
        {"time":1320,"intensity":0}
      ]
    },
    /* MANY OTHER COLORS */
  ],
  "response_code":0
}
```

Classes:

```
public class Prime
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ramps[] ramps { get; set; }
    public int response_code { get; set; }
}

public class ramps
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public points[] points { get; set; }
}

public class points
{
    public int time { get;set;}
    public int intensity { get; set;}
}
```

C# Code:

```
if (response2.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{     
    var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Prime>(responseFromServer);     
    Dg_View.DataSource = arr;
}
```

Unfortunately, the code above doesn't fill the `DataGridView` (`Dg_View`) with any data. Debugging `arr` I can see all the JSON in the correct format.

I want `color` to be the Row name with `time` being column header and the value in each box being `intensity`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I edited your question to reduce the huge and unnecessary code amount. When you ask, try to simplify the code as much as you can, it makes no sense to have 200 lines all repetitive and redunant, it's only a waste of time for the readers. A useful reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have hierarchical data therefore you should try Master/Detail Form approach https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8c0cxey(v=vs.110).aspx (you need at least two datagridView, one for the ramps, one for points)

Comment: looks quite complicated.. I am suprised that there is no easy way of publishing the data to a datagridview from an object.. I managed to do this with a nested for loop when the data was in xml format.

Comment: From the code you posted it is unclear what you want the `DataGridView` to look like. Your comment: _”I want color to be the Row name with time being column header and the value in each box being intensity.”_ … I am not sure how you would do this… Example, row 0 is “deep_red” and you want the `time` to be a column header where there would be multiple rows/columns of `point` objects. Can you draw or show what you want the grid to look like because your current description is difficult to picture.

Comment: From the posted code, to get the `ramp` objects into the grid you can use: `Dg_View.DataSource = arr.ramps;`… to get the points for the first `ramp` object you could use: `Dg_View.DataSource = arr.ramps[0].points;`. This is where it is unclear what you want the grid to look like since there is a collection within a collection. As @caner points out this appears to be a master/detail approach with at least two different grids.

Answer (score 0):

The `Prime` object, which is called `arr` in the code above, will contain more than one `Ramps` objects, therefore, it would appear that there would be a grid for each of the “Ramps” objects. This grid would have a single column to display the different “colors” of each `Ramps` object.
Since each `Ramps` object may contain more than one `Points` objects, then another grid could be used to display the different `time` and `intensity` `Points` for each `color` selected in the first grid.

The picture below demonstrates the approach described above. The grid on the left displays the different ‘color’s property for each of the `Ramps` objects. The grid on the right displays the different `time` and `intensity` properties of the `Points` objects for the currently selected row in the grid on the left.

If the user selects a different ‘color’ in the grid on the left, the grid on the right will update to reflect THAT selected `color`s `Points`.

[image]

The code below uses a global variable `PrimeObject` of type `Prime`. It contains all the data and needs to be visible to the `Ramps` `SelectionChanged` event in order to update the `Points` grid with the selected color in the `Ramps` grid. When the selection changes in the `Ramps` grid, a check is made for a valid selected cell, then the selected cells row index is obtained to determine which `Points` to display in the `Points` grid.

```
Prime PrimeObject;

private void btnReadJson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try {
    string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
    PrimeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Prime>(json);
    dgvRamps.DataSource = PrimeObject.ramps;
    lblColorGroup.Text = "Prime name: " + PrimeObject.name + " - Response Code: " + PrimeObject.response_code;
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error reading JSON file: " + jsonFile + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
  }
}

private void dgvColor_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try {
    if (dgvRamps.SelectedCells.Count > 0) {
      int colorIndex = dgvRamps.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
      dgvPoints.DataSource = PrimeObject.ramps[colorIndex].points;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("SelectionChanged: Error: " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting "Object referrence not set" on the line 
    dGview_points.DataSource = PrimeObject.ramps[colorIndex].points;

seems that it's not finding the PrimeObject object.

Comment: As I stated in my answer `PrimeObject` needs to be a global variable.

Comment: I tried adding this to the top of the class but it still gave me the above error.

code snipper below -


     namespace AI_Prime
{
 /// <summary>
 /// Description of MainForm.
 /// </summary>
 
 public partial class MainForm : Form
 {
  Prime PrimeObject;
  public MainForm()
  {
   //
   // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
   //
   InitializeComponent();
   
   //
   // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
   
   //
  }

Comment: You should update the code in your original question. Your last comment is useless.

Comment: sorry, I dont know how to format it correctly.. 

my issue with your code is that I dont know where in the code I should put the global variable.. I'm very new to c#.
i have -

namespace AI_Prime {
public partial clas MainForm : Form {}
}

Comment: I have seen the updated code, however without seeing how you are defining the `Prime` variable, the other issues in the edit are moot. Try and edit YOUR question.

Comment: hi, there is nothing more I can add to the question.. it contains the Prime class and the arr assignment (var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Prime>(responseFromServer); )  
I'm not defining the Prime variable anywhere else.

Comment: Change that line to `PrimeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Prime>(responseFromServer);`

Comment: Thanks.. that works!!

1 more question -  the class 'points' has a 'time' property as that is of integer value, however, I would like to convert this to hh:mm time format in the datagridview.. how can I achieve this at the class level?

Comment: I am not sure how you would convert an integer value to hh:mm:ss. It would appear making the `time` property in the `points` class either a `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` object instead of an integer, then do the conversion when you read the file or better yet, keep the value in a time format when you save the time info, that would eliminate any need to convert.

Comment: Error converting value 0 to type 'System.TimeSpan'. Path 'ramps[0].points[0].time', line 1, position 66. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.Int64 to System.TimeSpan.

At what point do I convert it?  as the only time it is read is when datagrid is bound to it?

<br>here's the get/set<br>

public TimeSpan time{get; set;}

Comment: ps I cant change the original as I'm pulling the json from an external site

Comment: I figured it out with -   public string time { get { return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(m_time)).ToString(@"hh\:mm");}